# Run command line tools as separate app

Tags: terminal, command-line, desktop

Is there a way to run command line tools as a separate app, so I can easily switch between them with apple+tab etc? I want this for things like a mail and irc client where I don't want to hunt down the terminal window to access them. Something like http://www.fluidapp.com but for the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can open separate instance of **Terminal.app** with

```
/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal &
```

You'll have separate icon on the Dock also. However You'll not be able to distinguish them in <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> because they are going to be called simply "Terminal" and have the same icons.

Comment: Unfortunately the inability to change the icon and that you can't give a script or command or anything to the new Terminal rules this out.

Answer (score -1):

[appify](https://sixohthree.com/1314/shell-scripts-as-applications-in-mac-os-x) seems to be what you're looking for…

Comment: This is definitely something interesting, but I didn't find a way to open a terminal window with it yet.